# How do I fill a new array with split pieces from an existing one? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm trying to split paragraphs of information from an array into a new one which is broken into individual words. I know that I need to use the String[] split(String regex), but I can't get this to output right.

What am I doing wrong?

(assume that sentences[i] is the existing array)

```
    String phrase = sentences[i];

    String[] sentencesArray = phrase.split("");

    System.out.println(sentencesArray[i]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `i` initialized to? How is `sentences` declared? The way I'm understanding, `sentences[i]` seems to refer to a specific word in the sentence as opposed to the entire sentence.

Comment: i is initialized like this: `for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {` sentences is a String[15] with each place in the array being occupied by a different sentence of text in quotes. -am I answering the right questions?

Answer (score 2):

It might be just the console output going wrong. Try replacing the last line by

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(sentencesArray));
```

The empty-string argument to `phrase.split("")` is suspect too. Try passing a word boundary:

```
phrase.split("\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an empty expression for splitting, try `phrase.split(" ")` and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] sentencesArray = phrase.split("");
```

The **regex** based on which the `phrase` needs to be split up is nothing here. If you wish to split it based on a space character, use:

```
String[] sentencesArray = phrase.split(" ");
                                   //   ^ Give this space
```

Comment: Missed the space there. Thank You, Mahesh!

Answer (score 0):

This does nothing useful:

```
String[] sentencesArray = phrase.split("");
```

you're splitting on empty string and it will return an array of the individual characters in the string, starting with an empty string.

It's hard to tell from your question/code what you're trying to do but if you want to split on words you need something like:

```
private static final Pattern SPC = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
.
.
String[] words = SPC.split(phrase);
```

The regex will **split on one or more spaces** which is probably what you want.